# Bootstrap 4 Inline Progress bar with <h3> element

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar, bootstrap-4

I am trying to show Bootstrap 4 progress bar inline with `<h3>` tag. Surprisingly, the bar gets on a little bit higher than the `<h3>` as below:

[image: progress_bar]

My attempt was to use `row` class with two portions. The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <h3 class="progress_title">Python</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 95%" aria-valuenow="95" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <h3 class="progress_title">JavaScript</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 90%" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

I have tested this code in this [codepen pen](https://codepen.io/arsho/full/rYBjdY/)

My question is, how to show the `<h3>` tag and progress bar inline with proper alignment? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bootstrap 4 class `align-self-center`

```
<div class="col-md-10 align-self-center">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 90%" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

it should align the child div to middle.

you can find more options [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#align-self)